# Unicode fonts not stacking correctly (especially Kokonor)

Tags: font, unicode

Correctly formatted Tibetan text, when pasted into Word, especially using the Kokonor font, does not stack correctly. Is there a solution or workaround to this?

Comment: Which version of Word.  Which keyboard layout.

Answer (score 1):

Word 2011 cannot support complex scripts.  Word 2016 can do so, but I think it is still a work in progress, and Tibetan may work properly only with the font Microsoft Himalaya.  Let us know if that one does do stacks correctly.

Sometimes 3rd party keyboard layouts also do not work right with Word.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for that clarification. Microsoft Himalaya generally works okay if you enter the text in Word. Text pasted from another program in another font, then changed to MS Himalaya sometimes does not do so well.

Comment: @stan  Thanks for that info.  Let MS know about the issues.  They put out updates almost every month and I have the impression they are gradually trying to fix the problems with complex scripts.